# object has no attribute 'map' error in pyspark 2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am running spark 2.4.4 with python 2.7 and IDE is pycharm.

The Input file contain encoded value in some column like given below.

```
.ʽ|!3-2-704A------------ (dotted line is space)
```

i am trying to get result like

3-2-704A

I tried below code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("Customers_v01.csv",header=True,sep=",");
myres = df.map(lambda x :x[1].decode('utf-8'))

print(myres.collect())
```

Error:

```
    myres = df.map(lambda x :x[1].decode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 1301, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

i am not sure what cause this error.... kindly help. is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> map is available on [Resilient Distributed Dataset (RDD)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession




spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv("Customers_v01.csv", header=True, sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
myres = df.rdd.map(lambda x: x[1].encode().decode('utf-8'))

print(myres.collect())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...but this only give result from 1st column. in file data looks COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
CM,   503004, (d$όνυ$F|'.h*Λ!ψμ=(.ξ;      ,.ʽ|!3-2-704 but i am trying to get result like CM,503004,,3-2-704 but getting only 503004. is it possible get result like CM,503004,,3-2-704. kindly help

Comment: you should modify "x[1]" in this line df.rdd.map(lambda x: x[1].encode().decode('utf-8')) to decode other columns